# Why can't I create this table in SQL (Oracle)?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to create a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE CCBCNV-LEGACYD.CV_PLSQL_COUNT  
(
      RUN_DTTM DATE NOT NULL,
      TABLE_NAME VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
      COUNT NUMBER(50) 
);
```

But i get the error:

```
Error starting at line 2 in command:
CREATE TABLE CCBCNV-LEGACYD.CV_PLSQL_COUNT  /* was CCBCNV-LEGACYD-CCBMIG, CHG */
(
      RUN_DTTM DATE NOT NULL,
      TABLE_NAME VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
      COUNT NUMBER(50) 
)
Error at Command Line:2 Column:20
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
00922. 00000 -  "missing or invalid option"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

What is happening with it? Do periods cause issues in table names(i.e is it something about the name)?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Oracle, but 'COUNT' is a reserved word in most SQL flavors, and would thus need to be quoted.

Comment: Does the hyphen in your schema name force you to quote the schema name too? there's no period in your table name. It's a table name (CV_PLSQL_COUNT) qualified by the schema name (CCBCNV-LEGACYD). You might need something like "CCBCNV-LEGACYD".CV_PLSQL_COUNT as the table name.

Comment: @Flimzy `COUNT` is not reserved in Oracle - but I wouldn't recommend it as a name.

Comment: @ChrisFarmer - Yes, I believe so. I ended up with "CCBCNV-LEGACYD.CV_PLSQL_COUNT"  and it worked, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

This finally worked for me:

```
CREATE TABLE "CCBCNV-LEGACYD.CV_PLSQL_COUNT" 
(
      RUN_DTTM DATE NOT NULL,
      TABLE_NAME VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
      "COUNT" NUMBER(30) 
);
```

Comment: That gives you a table called that - all 29 characters (and the limit is 30). If the part before the period is supposed to be the schema, you need to quote just that, or both parts separately: `"CCBCNV-LEGACYD"."CV_PLSQL_COUNT"`. Of course you always have to quote the schema if it has a dash in it, so whoever chose that name didn't do you any favours.

Comment: @AlexPoole - ah I was wondering why it wasn't working. Hmm,  wow that is subtle, thank you!! I will brush up on more SQL!!!

Comment: You might want to [read more about object naming](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements008.htm), and why quoted identifiers (like the schema here) are not a good idea.